# Adding an instance of a class derived from an interface to an array of interface pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, derived-class

I have an interface struct called IFoo.

```
struct IFoo
{
    void someFunc();

    virtual ~IFoo()
    {
    }
};
```

I have multiple structs derived from the interface. Each struct could have different constructors.

```
struct FooA : IFoo
{
    FooA(int i1, int i2)
    {
    }

    void someFunc()
    {
    }

    ~FooA()
    {
    }
};

struct FooB : IFoo
{
    FooB(int i)
    {
    }

    void someFunc()
    {
    }

    ~FooB()
    {
    }
};
```

I have a struct which (will) contain an array of pointers (in the example, just a single item to keep it simple).

```
struct FooContainer
{
    IFoo* fooItem;
};
```

FooContainer knows nothing about the derived instances.

I have written the following code, which appears to work.

Is it valid to set a pointer of IFoo to a pointer of a derived struct (say, FooA) in this manner?

Can anyone please advise if this is a good idea? It SEEMS to work fine... but I would prefer to know now of any problems I might get (memory problems etc) rather than find them further down the line. I know I will need to add missing methods... assignment operators, copy constructor etc :)

```
struct FooContainer
{
    IFoo* fooItem; // this will be an array of ifoo pointers in actual code

    FooContainer()
        : fooItem(0)
    {
    }

    template <typename T>
    void setFoo(const T& foo)
    {
        delete fooItem;

        fooItem = new T(foo); // this will add the item to the array
    }

    ~FooContainer()
    {
        delete fooItem;
    }
};
```

To be called like this:

```
FooContainer fooContainer = FooContainer();
fooContainer.setFoo(FooA(1, 1));
```

This is not C++11, just in case that matters.

Comment: This is ok on paper, the destructor is `virtual` so `delete` is well defined, although presumably `someFunc` is meant to be `virtual` too? The `setFoo` function is a little odd.

Comment: You should use smart pointers instead of raw pointers, though. In C++98, use a boost::ptr_vector in the array case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it valid to set a pointer of IFoo to a pointer of a derived struct (say, FooA)?

Yes, that is the perfectly right thing to do.

When you have a pointer to a derived type, and assign it to a pointer to one of its base types, the compiler automatically adjusts the pointer as required. Your call to `fooContainer.setFoo(FooA(1, 1))` makes the compiler instantiate

```
void setFoo<FooA>(const FooA& foo)
```

thus the new and assignment becomes

```
fooItem = new FooA(foo);
```

here, `new FooA(foo)` returns a `FooA*`, which is implicitly converted to a `IFoo*` as required by the assignment operator.

The only thing to look out for (and you already did that right), is to declare (and possibly define) a virtual destructor in the base class. This is needed, so that if you `delete fooItem`, the destructor of the actual object (e.g. `FooA::~FooA()`) is called.

For the derived classes, you don't need to define empty destructors.

Comment: Sweet. Just thought it was worth a quick check with "those that know". Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is how you are supposed to do it.

Although you may have intended for `someFunc` to be `virtual`?

Answer (score 0):

"Is it valid to set a pointer of IFoo to a pointer of a derived struct (say, FooA)?"

This is main essence of polymorphism in C++. You can pass any derived class pointer to function which is expecting base class pointer. And when you call any virtual function through that base pointer compiler would get you appropriate function called.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it valid to set a pointer of IFoo to a pointer of a derived struct (say, FooA)?
```

Yes this is perfectly valid. You can assign any derived class pointer to base class pointer provided base class should contain the virtual destructor.That you already provided

```
virtual ~IFoo()
{
}
```

In FooContainer class you can change setFoo function like this

```
struct FooContainer
{
    IFoo* fooItem; // this will be an array of ifoo pointers in actual code

    FooContainer() : fooItem(0)
    {
    }

    void setFoo(IFoo *obj)
    {
        delete fooItem;

        fooItem = obj;
    }

    ~FooContainer()
    {
        delete fooItem;
    }
```

};

Now in the caller code you have to change it like this

```
FooContainer fooContainer = FooContainer();
fooContainer.setFoo(new FooA(1, 1));
```

This way we can save the creation/destruction of one temporary instance of the FooA class.
Also for each class (say FooA, FooB) we can save the function template instantiation.